# About ordinals and cardinals in structural set theory

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, alternative-set-theories

Among the most important concepts of set theory for mathematical real life applications are [ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) and [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number). In [material set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/material+set+theory), ordinal numbers are defined as transitive sets, well-ordered by the membership relation. It can be shown that every well-ordered set is order isomorphic to a unique ordinal number. In categorical terms, ordinal numbers form a [skeleton](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton) of the category of well-ordered sets. By the well-ordering theorem, every set admits a well-ordering, whence is isomorphic to the underlying set of an ordinal number. Choosing for each isomorphism class the smallest such ordinal number, we obtain a skeleton of the category of sets given by the cardinal numbers. Note that by a sufficiently strong version of global choice, the existence of skeletons is immediate.

Now the categorical minded reader might feel uncomfortable, since quite a lot "evil" is going on here. First of all, working in [structural set theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/structural+set+theory) like [SEAR](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/SEAR) or [ETCS](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS), there is no such thing as a membership relation on a set. Secondly, skeletons are not really of use and most often, it is better to just prove theorems for all objects of a given category instead of restricting one's attention to representatives for each isomorphism class. Finally in structural set theory it is not even possible to express equality of abstract sets, hence uniqueness of the ordinal number associated to a well-ordered set.

So the following questions arise: Do we need to know a relatively concrete description of representatives for isomorphism classes in $\mathbf{Set}$ at all? Do we need material properties of those, like being a transitive set in set theory itself or elsewhere? Is it possible to recover the theory of [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) in structural set theory, replacing the partial order of ordinal numbers by the preorder aka thin category of well-ordered sets? Where do the technical details of developing the theory of ordinal numbers in material set theory move? Perhaps most of them disappear or are related to proving that well-ordered sets are "well-preordered" by the initial segment-relation? Are there philosophical issues when interpreting something like $\dim V=\aleph_0$ as "there is a basis of $V$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$" rather than "the mathematical object $\dim V$ is equal to the mathematical object $\aleph_0$"? Perhaps the first interpretation is more natural anyway?

Comment: Transfinite induction/recursion is purely order theoretic. It has nothing to do with set theory. However, if you want to do a transfinite construction on *all* the ordinals uniformly, ZF allows you to do exactly that internally to the theory.

Comment: I was uncomfortable already at "real life applications" for set theory.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't understand what the alternative to doing transfinite induction on all ordinals is, or what ZF does allow, which structural set theory might not allow.

Comment: @hardmath Of course, I mean applications in everyday life of a mathematician.

Comment: Okay. How do you say that "$x$ can be well-ordered" in structural set theory?

Comment: The same way: there exists a binary relation on $x$ such that etc.

Comment: @Zhen Lin: Okay. How do you say "binary relation"? And if you are planning on "a set of ordered pairs bla bla bla", then what is an ordered pair? (I'm not being facetious, I'm really asking)

Comment: These are all doable in a topos, in almost exactly the same way as in set theory. (The main difference is that we may take ordered pairs for granted.)

Comment: @JakobWerner: The category of well-ordered sets is not thin (unless you somehow restrict the morphisms), right? Consider $n \mapsto n$ and $n \mapsto n+1$ on $\mathbb{N}$, for instance.

Comment: That's a lot of questions for one post... Can you maybe focus it a bit? As it stands, it seems like a good answer might be essay-sized.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the more "philosophical" part: It is very useful to have a skeleton of $\mathsf{Set}$. First recall that natural numbers were invented to form a skeleton of $\mathsf{FinSet}$. Humans wanted to compare finite sets of objects in real life with each other, and it was useful to have a criterion when two finite sets are (what we now call) equipotent. This remains true for not-so-real-life objects in mathematics, and it remains true for non-finite sets. According to your profile ;-), you are more interested in algebra, so let me mention as an example the [Ulm invariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_(abelian_group)) which are cardinal numbers which classify certain torsion groups.

(Since you have asked a lot of questions, it could be a good idea to ask them separately, if you are still interested in them.)

Answer (score -1):

In the [Homotopy Type Theory Book](http://homotopytypetheory.org/book/), a more structural approach to define cardinal and ordinal numbers is presented. See Chapter 10:

> - The type of cardinal numbers is the 0-truncation of the type Set of sets:
>     $\mathrm {Card} :≡ ||\mathrm{Set}||_0$
> - An ordinal is a set $A$ with an extensional well-founded relation which is
>     transitive, i.e. satisfies $∀(a, b, c : A).(a < b) → (b < c) → (a < c)$.